# MySQL as ASP Session state not working on shared host, only localhost

Tags: asp.net, mysql, web-config, session-state

I have encountered this problem before on a few shared hosts but cant remember the fix. I have spent almost 2 days googling and I have even gone through 2 external hd's of backups of old projects and read the web.configs but I just cant put my find it and I dont think I am googling the correct terms...

I am using Mysql Connector/Net to store asp session state. 
The mysql db is on the hosting server ( I have no mysql locally).
Opening a page locally creates a session in the db.
Opening a page on the host does not.

I have seen this issue before but was a long time ago and I have searched a few of the answered questions here but not too extensive, I'm sick of searching.

Help Please

Mat

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue. The db user has connect/update permission from one host (locally), but not from the other (hosting server).

Comment: No, I just solved it after taking a break, it seems my visual studio is somehow (weirdly) overwriting the mysql.data dll with a different version from the one specified in the web.config. It seem's this question was a bit hasty and I should have just taken a breal and thought about the problem rationally.